# Ubuntu Boots, But stays on shell!

Tags: boot, live-usb

I have a Dell Optiplex 160L and I'm booting Ubuntu 13.04 from a LinuxLiveKey USB. It loads all the way through the purple Ubuntu loading screen then goes back to shell. then it gets stuck on

> ubuntu@ubuntu:~$

Also could it be a problem that I'm using a 1 GB USB?
Is there a reason why it doesn't boot? Or is my hardware to crappy for it?

Comment: Ok on that shell try to execute this command: `sudo pkill -u ubuntu`. You would get a login screen, on login screen chose some different `desktop environment` like `gnome-classic(no effects)` and then login.

Comment: The problem with that though is that I'm INSTALLING ubuntu and i don't have it but on a USB

Comment: Yes, I noticed that, you have to execute the command and login, When some options will come like `Try Ubuntu` or `Install Ubuntu` you have to chose `Try Ubuntu`. Once loged in then you can install ubuntu, by clicking `Install Ubuntu` icon from your desktop. Give it a try, it would not take much time. If doesn't work then we'll search for another answer..

Comment: I guess it was the size of the USB because I put a 16 GB in and then it worked without going directly to shell!

Comment: Sounds good!! Post it as an answer.. It may help others..